Vite proxy doesn't connect to localserver Express
I'm building a full stack app with the backend developed in Node/Express and the front end managed by React/Vite. If on the frontend I'm fetching data straight from localhost and no proxy configuration in vite.config.js everything works as expected:
APP.JSX
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setMessage(data.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default App


VITE.CONFIG.JS
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],

})

SERVER - APP.JS
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors')
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(cors())

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

But when i define the localhost in the proxy configuration to manage all requests and use absolute path in REACT the only thing i get in the browser is the JSON object on itself so i  see printed {message:Hello World'} and this is not coming from fetching or anything is just the response i have if i connect to the frontend localserver
APP.JSX
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setMessage(data.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default App


VITE.CONFIG.JS
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server:{
    proxy:{
      '/': 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  }

})


How can i solve this issue?
